# ZSH vi normal mode to move around printed text

Tags: zsh, vi

Can I use zsh vi normal mode to move around previous commands output or the printed text in the shell to copy/yank it ?

For example in the screenshot below. I want to move to the output of `ls` to copy something. When I press `j/k` zsh cycle my command history but doesn't move up to the printed text. `j/k` move one line `down/up` only when I have multiple line command that I'm currently writing but haven't executed yet.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To the best of my knowledge, the ability to access the output of commands interactively is the domain of your terminal (-emulator), not the shell. You would use commands like `sed`, `awk`, `grep`, possibly in a pipe, to access, manipulate and use output you know in advance is the part you are interested in.

To access the output with keyboard shortcuts/command-keys, I suggest using the like of `tmux` - it allows to copy/yank from the whole terminal display as if it was a text-file in an editor.